# Why is an element which should be 100% in width have an element to its right?

Tags: html, css

I have this class:

```
.top-level-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

...which is applied to this:

```
<template name="mnuScheduler">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
```

...yet the menu bar (comprised of uls and lis) sits right on top of the element below it (an HTML Table), and a Template that's loaded dynamically lines up to its right.

Based on the CSS, there should be some space between the menu bar and the table, and the Template should display below the menu bar, as the HTML Table does before it's displaced (using Meteor's Template.dynamic) by the other Template, which for now is just a placeholder.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

So why is an element which should be 100% in width not, and which should have a margin along the bottom doesn't?

### UPDATE

Here is the pertinent CSS and HTML (this is from a Meteor app, so the HTML has Spacebars code (template language) mixed in).

CSS:

```
/* Menu-specific styles/rules  */
.third-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.third-level-menu > li {
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
.second-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.second-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: navy;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 60%;
}
.top-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    //width: 150px;
    width: 20%;
    background: black;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}
/* Menu Link Styles */
.top-level-menu a
/* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 16px Candara, Calibri, 'Segoe UI', serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
/* End of Menu-specific Styles */
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <TITLE>Crew Scheduler</TITLE>
</head>

<body TEXT="#000000">

<div class="container">
    {{> mnuScheduler}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=currentTemplate}}
</div>

</body>

<template name="mnuScheduler">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">Schedules</a>
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li name="mniOpenExisting" id="mniOpenExisting">Open Existing</li>
                <li>Create New...
                                  <ul class="third-level-menu">
                        <li name="mniCreateNewScheduleBasedOnExisting" id="mniCreateNewScheduleBasedOnExisting">Based on Existing</li>
                        <li name="mniCreateNewScheduleFromScratch" id="mniCreateNewScheduleFromScratch">From Scratch</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li name="mniSaveCurrentSchedule" id="mniSaveCurrentSchedule">Save Current</li>
                <li name="mniEmailCurrentSchedule" id="mniEmailCurrentSchedule">Email Current</li>
                <li name="mniPrintCurrentSchedule" id="mniPrintCurrentSchedule">Print Current</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Job/Locations</a>
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                        <li name="mniAddNewJobLoc" id="mniAddNewJobLoc">Add New</li>
              <li name="mniViewOrEditJobLoc" id="mniViewOrEditJobLoc">View or Edit</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Workers</a>
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                        <li name="mniAddNewWorker" id="mniAddNewWorker">Add New</li>
              <li name="mniViewOrEditWorker" id="mniViewOrEditWorker">View or Edit</li>
              <li name="mniWorkerPreferences" id="mniWorkerPreferences">Preferences</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Rules</a>
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li name="mniSetRules" id="mniSetRules">Establish/Maintain</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a>
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li name="mniAbout" id="mniAbout">About</li>
                <li name="mniHowTo" id="mniHowTo">How To...</li>
                <li name="mniContact" id="mniContact">Contact Us</li>
                <li name="mniAcquireLicense" id="mniAcquireLicense">Acquire License</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: We need to see more of the markup and styles to know. At least enough code to reproduce the issue should be included.

Comment: Can you post the HTML + Styles of the parent container?

Comment: Please see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.top-level-menu{
width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

you modify css class .top-level-menu

Answer (score 1):

Width or height in `%` is usually in relation to the parent element. In this case `name="mnuScheduler"` probably has a width that is less than *100% of the viewport width* which is why the child also has a width less than 100% of the viewport width.

You could potentially solve this issue by using `width: 100vw;` on `.top-level-menu`.

That said a closer look at the markup and styling and maybe a fiddle wouldn't hurt.